# MarkerWithLabel not working AGAIN

Tags: google-maps-markers

My Marker with Label program stopped working in March. Adding &v=3.15 fixed it. Now, even with the &v=3.15 only the last marker is displayed. All the other markers are missing. The example at: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/basic.html also only shows one marker.

Any ideas on how to correct it this time?

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a new version of markerwithlabel 1.1.9 which fixed this for me, https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/. Please also see [MarkerWithLabel stopped working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203336/markerwithlabel-stopped-working-correctly)

Comment: Downloading that Javascript corrected the problem. Thanks!