# Google Maps 3.15 Can Only Displays One Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently, I was having an issue getting multiple markers to display using Google Maps version 3.16. After doing some research, [I saw that versions 3.16 and greater had issues displaying markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203336/markerwithlabel-stopped-working-correctly), so I reverted to 3.15.

I am now discovering that version 3.15 is no longer displaying multiple markers with labels either.

I make the map in an init javascript function:

```
TripMap.map = new google.maps.Map($('#tripMap')[0], mapOptions);
```

Then in a later method, I make a set of lats and longs and create MarkerWithLabels:

```
//Lat Lngs will eventuall be needed for all coords
var originLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.resultVal.oycord, result.resultVal.oxcord);
var boardLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.resultVal.bycord, result.resultVal.bxcord);
var alightLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.resultVal.aycord, result.resultVal.axcord);
var destinationLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.resultVal.dycord, result.resultVal.dxcord);

//Create marker labels
makePathPointLabel = function (coordinate, labelContent, colorCode) {
    return new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: coordinate,
        map: TripMap.map,                          
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 50),
        labelStyle: {
            'color': '#000',
            'fontWeight': 'bold'
        },
        icon: {
            url:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + labelContent + '|' + colorCode + '|000000'
        }
    });
}

//Create map markers, each with a different colors. Colors are hard coded, and have no meaning other than making
// the map "pop" more at this point. May want to add options to change colors in the future. 
TripMap.originMarker = makePathPointLabel(originLatLng, "O", '008000');
TripMap.destinationMarker = makePathPointLabel(destinationLatLng, "D", 'FF0000');
TripMap.boardMarker = makePathPointLabel(boardLatLng, "B", '008000');
TripMap.alightMarker = makePathPointLabel(alightLatLng, "A", 'FF0000');

//Sets the zoom level of the google map to incorporate all four of the trip place markers
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(originLatLng);
bounds.extend(boardLatLng);
bounds.extend(alightLatLng);
bounds.extend(destinationLatLng);
TripMap.map.fitBounds(bounds);

var tripPathLegend = document.getElementById('tripPathLegend');
tripPathLegend.index = 1;

TripMap.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(tripPathLegend);
```

I have already verified that the coords are different form each other, and valid. I also verified that I am actually loading the 3.15 version of the api.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** I added more code above. I do nothing with the markers after they are displayed on the map. [Here is an example marker](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O%7C008000%7C000000) (they all generate correctly). I am also using [MarkerWithLabel v1.1.7](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.7/src/markerwithlabel.js).

Comment: Could it be a problem with the MarkerWithLabel library?  Is the Google Charts URLs you're using producing the correct icons based on the different arguments?  What are you doing (i.e. show us the code) with `TripMap.originMarker`, `TripMap.destinationMarker` etc?

Comment: See edits. I dont do anything with the markers, but it appears that the marker library is working correctly. For example, if I comment out one of the lines like `TripMap.alightMarker = makePathPointLabel(alightLatLng, "A", 'FF0000');` another one will generate correctly. I just cannot get more than one marker to generate

Comment: [3.15 is no longer available](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), it has been "retired".  The latest version of MarkerWithLabel fixes [your issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6447).

Comment: I was unaware of the upgrade. Working version of MarkerWithLabel (from the link @geocodezip provided) 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js